# Adding and Removing objects from Ember Data async hasMany relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a view which renders a parent object with a loop of child views underneath. The form to add new is on the same view. When I save the child object, I know it has be pushed into the parent objects child promise array. But when I attempted to remove the child object the object was deleted by the view wasn't updated so now I'm saving the parent, child and then reloading the parent model.

It seems like a bit of overkill to manage the relationship. Am I missing something or is this currently the correct way to manage async relationships in Ember Data. I'm currently using Beta 8 version.

Some code snippets:

Parent Model:

```
var parent = DS.model.extend({
    name: DS.attr(),
    children: DS.hasMany('parent/child', {async: true})
});

parent.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        {id: 1, name: "TEST", children: [1, 2]}
    ]
});
```

Child Model:

```
var child = DS.model.extend({
    name: DS.attr(),
    parent: DS.belongsTo('parent')
});

child.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        {id: 1, name: "TEST", parent: 1},
        {id: 2, name: "TEST", parent: 1}
    ]
});
```

The screen which inserts new child records is in the same route as the parent model and I have the following two actions:

```
actions:
{
    save: function()
    {
        var self = this;

        var child = this.store.createRecord('parent/child', {name: 'test', parent: this.get('model'});

        child.save().then(function(record)
        {
            self.get('content.children').pushObject(record);

            parent.save().then(function(){
                self.get('model').reload();
            });
        });
    },

    delete: function(id)
    {
        this.store.find('parent/child', id).then(function(child)
        {
            child.deleteRecord();
            child.save();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: managing async relationships is Ember Data sucks right now, and is definitely a major issue that they are tackling.  Honestly I've found it easier to roll my own record management software as of now.  Whether or not it's easier for everyone is debatable, but currently as it stands, Ember Data makes easy things easy, and hard things super complex.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, since children is async, you should be fetching it before attempting to push the object, in this case maybe it's already been fetched so it isn't hosing you, but the proper pattern when dealing with async relationships is as follows:

```
save: function()
{
    var self = this;

    var child = this.store.createRecord('parent/child', {name: 'test', parent: this.get('model'});

    child.save().then(function(record)
    {
        self.get('children').then(function(children){
          // making sure children has resolved before attempting to use it
          children.pushObject(record);

          parent.save();//.then(function(){
            // this shouldn't be necessary
            // self.get('model').reload();
            // });
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: I've updated the action and removed the model.reload. The children promiseArray is updated [yay], however when I run my delete method, the view doesn't seem to update [boo]. This was the original issue which I ran into before posting this question and the reason behind the reload [since I'm not transitioning away then coming back to the route].

I've reinstated the reload and it all works again. I'm looking at possibly moving back to straight up JSON since this is doing my head in!